# Parsing values in JSON

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am trying to pass some values to my PHP page and return JSON but for some reason I am getting the error "Unknown error parsererror". Below is my code. Note that if I alert the params I get the correct value.

```
function displaybookmarks()
{
    var bookmarks = new String();
    for(var i=0;i<window.localStorage.length;i++)
    {
        var keyName = window.localStorage.key(i);
        var value = window.localStorage.getItem(keyName);
        bookmarks = bookmarks+" "+value;
    }

    getbookmarks(bookmarks);
} 

function getbookmarks(bookmarks){   
//var surl =  "http://www.webapp-testing.com/includes/getbookmarks.php";
var surl =  "http://localhost/Outlish Online/includes/getbookmarks.php";
var id = 1;
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: surl,
    data: "&Bookmarks="+bookmarks,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    cache : false,
    jsonp : "onJSONPLoad",
    jsonpCallback: "getbookmarkscallback",
    crossDomain: "true",
    success: function(response) {
       alert("Success");
    },
    error: function (xhr, status) {           
       alert('Unknown error ' + status);
    }       
   });      
}

  function getbookmarkscallback(rtndata) 
 { 
$('#pagetitle').html("Favourites");
var data = "<ul class='table-view table-action'>";
for(j=0;j<window.localStorage.length;j++)
{

     data = data + "<li><a href='#' onclick=\"History.pushState({state:null},'article,"+rtndata[j].id+"','article'); return false;\">" + rtndata[j].title + "</a></li>";

}
data = data + "</ul>";
$('#listarticles').html(data);
 }
```

Below is my PHP page:

```
    <?php
    $id = $_REQUEST['Bookmarks'];
    $articles = explode(" ", $id);
    $link = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die('Could not connect to mysql server' . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db('joomla15',$link) or die('Cannot select the DB');
    /* grab the posts from the db */
    $query = "SELECT * FROM jos_content where id='$articles[$i]'";
    $result = mysql_query($query,$link) or die('Errant query:  '.$query);
    /* create one master array of the records */
    $posts = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < count($articles); $i++)
    {
    if(mysql_num_rows($result)) {   
    while($post = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$posts[] = $post;     
    }
    }
    }
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo $_GET['onJSONPLoad']. '('. json_encode($posts) . ')';  
    @mysql_close($link);
    ?>
```

Any idea why I am getting this error?

Comment: Which of the four code snippets displays the error?

Comment: This needs basic debugging. When are you getting that error and what does the JSON response look like when you are getting it?

Comment: json returns nothing it is not getting the variable I am sending it which is bookmarks. However if I alert bookmarks I am getting the correct value. The error is displayed when the callback function is called

Answer (score 0):

This is not json

```
"&Bookmarks="+bookmarks,
```

Comment: I know this is not json i said it returns jason

Comment: ok this is strange I have used this in another context and it works?

Answer (score 0):

You're not sending JSON to the server in your `$.ajax()`. You need to change your code to this:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    data: {
      Bookmarks: bookmarks
    },
    ...
});
```

Only then will `$_REQUEST['Bookmarks']` have your `id`.

As a sidenote, you should not use `alert()` in your jQuery for debugging. Instead, use `console.log()`, which can take multiple, comma-separated values. Modern browsers like Chrome have a console that makes debugging far simpler.

Comment: ok this is strange I have used this in another context and it works? Please note bookmarks is a string which looks like 34 45 65

Comment: @KernElliott It should not have worked in another context. You should be sending JSON to the server as above. Change your code as indicated and it should work.

Comment: will give it a shot tks a lot

Comment: @KernElliott Sure. If it solves your problem, be sure to upvote/accept the answer. And read my note at the end.

Comment: still gettin a parse error within firebug it says missing ; before statement for the php code page

Comment: Before what statement for the PHP?

Comment: i actually figured it out the error was actually in my php sql statements and not the actually jquery call